# htaccess file not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an `.htaccess` file with the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.html|/[^.]*)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ $1.html [NC]
</IfModule>
```

But it is not working. I want to change the URL, e.g., `www.example.com/about.html` to `www.example.com/about` and so on.

Comment: _"its urgent"_ You should not promise what you can't deliver. But please tell what is _"not working"_. Any errors in the logs?

Comment: @Piyush is `AllowOverride` set in your *httpd.conf* in the first place for the htaccess to work?

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Keep this in your `.htaccess` snippets file if you don't understand it for the next time. Replace `.html` with the file extension you need to remove.